# Shift text in ggplot up

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using the this code gives the plot printed below. As you can see the percentages are printed on the border of the bars. I would like to have them above the bars. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
p <- ggplot(data=iris, aes(x=factor(Species), fill=factor(Species)))
p + geom_bar() + scale_fill_discrete(name="Species")  + labs(x="") +geom_text(aes(y = (..count..),label = scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..))), stat="bin",colour="darkgreen") + theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]

Comment: play around with vjust: `geom_text(aes(....), vjust=-0.5)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add an arbitrary value to y.

```
p <- ggplot(data=iris, aes(x=factor(Species), fill=factor(Species)))
p + geom_bar() + scale_fill_discrete(name="Species")  + labs(x="") +geom_text(aes(y = (..count..) + 10,label = scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..))), stat="bin",colour="darkgreen") + theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]

Or, as per Heroka's comment, use vjust, which is a better solution

```
p <- ggplot(data=iris, aes(x=factor(Species), fill=factor(Species)))
p + geom_bar() + scale_fill_discrete(name="Species")  + labs(x="") + 
  geom_text(aes(y = (..count..), 
                label = scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..))), 
            stat="bin", 
            colour="darkgreen", vjust = -0.5) + 
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]

But as this makes things quite cramped at the top you might want to add `+ expand_limits(y = c(0, 60))` to give you a bit more space for the labels.

Comment: That's not very generalizable, as you need to know the distribution of the data beforehand.

Comment: True. Your comment about vjust is better.

Comment: Feel free to edit your answer, it doesn't warrant a new anser.